# How do you find the minimum value of $| OB|$. That is, find the shortest distance from the origin to a point on the line?

Tags: vectors

The vector equation for this question is $r(t) = i − 4 j + k + t(i + 2 j − k)$, t ∈ R.

$\vec{OB} = (1+t)i + (2t-4)j + (1-t)k$. The magnitude $|OB| = \sqrt{(1+t)^2 + (2t-4)^2 + (1-t)^2}$ which simplified to $\sqrt{6t^2 - 16t + 18}$.

Now I am stuck with trying to find the minimum value of $| OB|$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is recommended to add all the relevant information regarding a question in the body and not only in the title. This makes the question more clear.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind the next time I post a question. 

Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 4):

You could complete the square:

$$
\begin{align}
|OB|^2 &= 6t^2 - 16t + 18 \\
& = 6 \left[ t^2 - \frac{16}{6}t \right] +18 \\
& = 6 \left[ \left(t-\frac{16}{12} \right)^2 - \left(\frac{16}{12} \right)^2 \right] +18 \\
& =6 \left(t-\frac{4}{3} \right)^2 +\frac{22}{3}
\end{align}
$$

from which you can see the minimum of $|OB|$ is $\sqrt{\frac{22}{3}}$ when $t=4/3$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this problem is from Calculus 3/Multivariable Calculus. To find the minimum or maximum of a function, a good idea is to find the critical points (Calc I). Since this a single variable function in terms of $t$, we just take the derivative with respect to $t$ and set $=0$.

First note that for any $t \neq 0$, $\sqrt{6t^2 - 16t + 18} \neq 0$. So we get
$$
\frac{\text{d}|OB|}{\text{d}t} = \frac{6t - 8}{\sqrt{6t^2 - 16t + 18}} = 0 \implies 6t - 8 = 0 \implies t = \frac{4}{3}.
$$

To show this is a minimum, we can do the first derivative test, second derivative test, or graph the function. In this case, the second derivative test (for example) shows

$$
\frac{\text{d}^2|OB|}{\text{d}t^2} = \frac{44}{(6t^2 - 16t + 18)^{3/2}} > 0
$$

so the function is concave up everywhere, and hence the critical point is a minimum. From there, simply plug in $t = \frac{4}{3}$ into the original equation for $|OB|$ and you get the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

The line $B(t) = (1, -4, 1) + t (1,2,-1) = B_0 + t B_1 $

And you want to determine the minimum distance from the origin $O(0,0,0)$ to $B(t)$.

If you take the vector $O B_0 = B_0 $, then the minimum distance to the line is

$ d = | B_0 | \sin \theta $

Where $\theta$ is the angle between $B_0$ and $B_1$.  This means that the distance is given by

$ d =  \dfrac{\| B_0 \times B_1 \|}{\| B_1 \| } $

Now, $ B_0 \times B_1 = (1, -4, 1) \times (1, 2, -1) = (2,2,6) = 2 (1,1,3)$

And $ \| B_1 \| = \sqrt{ 1^2 + 2^2+ (-1)^2 } = \sqrt{6 } $

Therefore, the minimum distance is

$ d = \dfrac{ 2 \sqrt{ 11}}{\sqrt{6}} =\dfrac{ \sqrt{66} }{3} $

To verify this answer, we can take a different approach, namely, we want the vector $B(t)$ to be perpendicular to $B_1$, and this means

$ (B_0 + t B_1) \cdot B_1 = 0 $

So that

$ t^* = - \dfrac{B_0 \cdot B_1 }{B_1 \cdot B_1 } = - \dfrac{ -8 }{6} = \dfrac{4}{3} $

Hence,

$ B(t^*) = (1, -4, 1) + ( 4/3, 8/3, -4/3) = (7/3, -4/3, -1/3) $

Hence,

$ d = \| B(t^*) \| = (1/3) \sqrt{ 7^2 + 4^2 + 1^2 } = \dfrac{\sqrt{66}}{3} $